# How call variable outside function .each with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to access the value of a nested each() function outside of the function.

I have code below or http://jsfiddle.net/z36UK/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." id="ds-canho"> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urlx=[];  
  parseXml();
  alert(urlx);
  console.log(urlx);

  $.mobile.loading( "show" );
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http://saigonpearl.info/home/notype/-0-trang-chu.html%27%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27tindang%27%5D%22&diagnostics=true',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });


  function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("div.tindang").each(function() {

      var url = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
      urlx= url.replace('#menutop','');
      $("ul#ds-canho").append('<li>' + $(this).find('h3').text() + '</li>');
      $('ul#ds-canho').listview('refresh');
      $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: you want to use the value or the variable who'z having the value? in this case the `url` variable, right?

Comment: -1 because you didn't make any effort to format your code in a readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update below js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {                   
  $.mobile.loading( "show" );
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http://saigonpearl.info/home/notype/-0-trang-chu.html%27%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27tindang%27%5D%22&diagnostics=true',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
  $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    parseXml();
  });
  function parseXml(xml) {
    window.urlx = '';
    $(xml).find("div.tindang").each(function() {

      var url = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
          urlx = url.replace('#menutop','');

      $("ul#ds-canho").append('<li>' + $(this).find('h3').text() + '</li>');
      $('ul#ds-canho').listview('refresh');
      $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
    });
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Add [FSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitbatham/z36UK/7/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the `each`, is it? You can easily put the `urlx` variable there and assign to it from the inside:

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    var urlx;
    $(xml).find("div.tindang").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
        urlx = url.replace('#menutop','');
        $("ul#ds-canho").append('<li>' + $(this).find('h3').text() + '</li>');
        $('ul#ds-canho').listview('refresh');
        $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
    });
    console.log(urlx);
    // if you wanted an array, use `urlx = [];` and `urlx.push(…);`
}
```

However, where you currently have placed the log and alert statements is

- before the ajax request
- outside of the ajax request callback

which means that it cannot work. You need to put them inside the callback, because you [cannot `return` the data outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572).